# How to apply below code for multiple fields?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravity, gravityforms

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_20_6', function( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {

   if ( strpos( $field->cssClass, 'require_english' ) !== false && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $value) ) {

      $result['is_valid'] = false;
      $result['message'] = 'Please enter only English characters';

   }

   return $result;

}, 10, 4 );

add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_29', function( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {

   $target_fields = array( 1, 9, 30, 54, 59, 61, 71, 73, 83, 85, 33 ); // Add the IDs of the fields you want to validate

   if ( in_array( $field->id, $target_fields ) && strpos( $field->cssClass, 'require_bengali' ) !== false && !preg_match('/^[ঀ-৿\s]+$/u', $value) ) {

      $result['is_valid'] = false;
      $result['message'] = 'Please enter only Bengali characters';

   }

   return $result;

}, 10, 4 );
```

I try above code but I got error " There has been a critical error on this website."